# Edit kubernetes resource using kubectl run --command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to create a pod run a command edit an exist resource , but its not working
My CR is

```
apiVersion: feature-toggle.resource.api.sap/v1
kind: TestCR
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  enabled: true
  strategies:
    - name: tesst
      parameters:
        perecetage: "10"
```

The command I am trying to run is

```
kubectl run kube-bitname --image=bitnami/kubectl:latest -n  my-namespace --command -- kubectl get testcr test -n my-namespace -o json | jq '.spec.strategies[0].parameters.perecetage="66"' | kubectl apply -f -
```

But This not work ? any idea ?

Comment: Can you add more context? I would like to understand why you need to let it run in a separate pod. Did you think about other options?

Comment: Can you just run that `kubectl` command locally, delete everything up through the `--command --` options?  Are you running the temporary pod with a ServiceAccount with RBAC permissions to read TestCR objects?  When you say it doesn't work, what does happen?

Comment: @DavidMaze it works if I just run the kubectl without the kubectl run --command

Comment: @Manuel I have a cronJob scheduled every 2 days with create a job. The job will create the pod through this command for updating my custom CR

Comment: Did you check for other options?

Comment: `But This not work ?` -- consider adding more info here. Eg, what do you see? a silent failure or any other sort of error.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you post more info about the error o the trace that are you getting executing the command, but I have a question that could be a good insight about what is happening here.

Has the ***kubectl*** command that you are running inside the ***bitnami/kubectl:latest*** any context that allow it to connect to your cluster?
If you take a look into the [kubectl docker hub documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kubectl) you can see that you should map a config file to the pod in order to connect to your own cluster.

```bash
$ docker run --rm --name kubectl -v /path/to/your/kube/config:/.kube/config bitnami/kubectl:latest
```